# Copyright statement not building

Tags: apache-fop, dita

For me, this builds the preface content, but no copyright matter. The file location is correct.

From my ditamap:

```
<frontmatter>
 <notices format="dita" href="preface/src/c_copyright.xml" linking="none" navtitle="Copyright and disclaimer" scope="local" toc="no" type="concept">
 </notices>
 <booklists>
    <toc/>
 </booklists>
 <preface navtitle="nested Preface inside">
    <topicref format="ditamap" href="maps/GSGettingStarted_preface.ditamap" navtitle="GSGettingStarted_preface">
    </topicref>
 </preface>
```

Am I using the notices element incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: The DITA look correct. Which processor are you using to process the map and how does the output differ from what you expect?

Comment: I expected the content from c_copyright.xml to appear in the built book. I'm building with:  



    [echo] * DITA-OT version = 1.8.4  
    [echo] * XML parser = Xerces  
    [echo] * XSLT processor = Saxon