# Copyright symbol breaks pdf building if placed in preface

Tags: xsl-fo, dita

EDIT:
I found out that my problem is probably related with something very characteristic for our plugin. So basically it will be hard to ask about it, but I will leave that questions, because I think that someone can find here good points made by community, that might be useful.

I have really strange problem. I have preface, which looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN"
"../../dtd/topic.dtd">
<topic  id="copyright" rev="1">
    <title></title>
    <shortdesc></shortdesc>
    <body>
        <p id="statement">©Copyright 2015 All rights reserved</p>
    </body>
</topic>
```

And everything is ok, if I place it as chapter. But, when I try to make it as a preface, I got build error. I know thats all happens because of copyright symbol, simply because if you remove it, everything working normally - in chapter, and in preface.

```
[fop] [ERROR] Anttask - Error rendering fo file: C:\DITA-OT2.0.1_client_bin\DITA-OT2.0.1\temp\pdf\9030310-OperationsGuide\topic.fo <org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:inline" is not a valid child of "fo:root"! (See position 12:-1)
      [fop] net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:inline" is not a valid child of "fo:root"! (See position 12:-1)>org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:inline" is not a valid child of "fo:root"! (See position 12:-1)
      [fop] net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:inline" is not a valid child of "fo:root"! (See position 12:-1)
```

It might be specific problem to ours code, because we edited it slightly. But, if anybody had this normally, I would like to hear what could cause it.

FO code:

stage2:

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" space-before.optimum="5pt" space-after.optimum="5pt" id=""><fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="proportional-column-width(0.2)"/><fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="proportional-column-width(1.0)"/><fo:table-body id=""><fo:table-row id=""><fo:table-cell id="" text-align="right"><fo:block space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" padding-bottom="3pt" text-align="left">Copyright</fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell id=""><fo:block space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" padding-bottom="3pt" text-align="left"><fo:block font-family="HelveticaNeueLTStdThin" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" start-indent="0cm" text-indent="0cm" margin-left="0cm" space-before="3pt" space-after="3pt">©Copyright 2015  rights reserved</fo:block>
              </fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row id=""><fo:table-cell id="" text-align="right"><fo:block space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" padding-bottom="3pt" text-align="left">Intended Purpose</fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell id=""><fo:block space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" padding-bottom="3pt" text-align="left"><fo:block font-family="HelveticaNeueLTStdThin" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" start-indent="0cm" text-indent="0cm" margin-left="0cm" space-before="3pt" space-after="3pt">
                   This guide provides details of the features provided proactive recovery.</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row id=""><fo:table-cell id="" text-align="right"><fo:block space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" padding-bottom="3pt" text-align="left">Conventions Used</fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell id=""><fo:block space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" padding-bottom="3pt" text-align="left"><fo:block font-family="HelveticaNeueLTStdThin" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" start-indent="0cm" text-indent="0cm" margin-left="0cm" space-before="3pt" space-after="3pt">This guide uses the following format for tips and additional information:
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="20pt"/><fo:table-column column-width="100% - 32pt"/><fo:table-body><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell padding-right="5pt" start-indent="0pt"><fo:block><fo:external-graphic src="url(file:/C:/DITA-OT2.0.1_client_bin/DITA-OT2.0.1/temp/pdf/9030310-OperationsGuide/Configuration/OpenTopic/cfg/common/artwork/Notice_Tip_A3A5.svg)"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell start-indent="0pt"><fo:block font-family="helveticaNeueLTStdThinIt" font-size="10pt" padding-top="1.9px" padding-bottom="1.9px" margin-top="3pt" margin-bottom="3pt" page-break-inside="avoid" page-break-before="avoid" page-break-after="avoid" border-bottom-style=" solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-bottom-color=" #000000" padding="1.9pt" border-top-style=" solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-top-color=" #000000" margin-left="2cm" id=""><fo:inline start-indent="0cm"><fo:inline float="left" clear="both" height="20px" margin-top="0px" padding-left="0cm" margin-left="0px" page-break-before="avoid" page-break-after="avoid"/></fo:inline>  Additional information relating to the current section.</fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table>
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="20pt"/><fo:table-column column-width="100% - 32pt"/><fo:table-body><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell padding-right="5pt" start-indent="0pt"><fo:block><fo:external-graphic src="url(file:/C:/DITA-OT2.0.1_client_bin/DITA-OT2.0.1/temp/pdf/9030310-OperationsGuide/Configuration/OpenTopic/cfg/common/artwork/NOTICE_Caution_A3A5.svg)"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell start-indent="0pt"><fo:block font-family="helveticaNeueLTStdThinIt" font-size="10pt" padding-top="1.9px" padding-bottom="1.9px" margin-top="3pt" margin-bottom="3pt" page-break-inside="avoid" page-break-before="avoid" page-break-after="avoid" border-bottom-style=" solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-bottom-color=" #000000" padding="1.9pt" border-top-style=" solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-top-color=" #000000" margin-left="2cm" id=""><fo:inline start-indent="0cm"><fo:inline float="left" clear="both" height="20px" margin-top="0px" padding-top="0px" padding-bottom="0px" padding-left="1.9cm" margin-left="0px" page-break-before="avoid" page-break-after="avoid"/></fo:inline>  Indicates a hazardous situation which, if not avoided, could result in moderate injury, damage the product, or lead to loss of data.</fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table>
```

stage3:

```
<fo:table id="" space-after="5pt" space-after.optimum="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-before.optimum="5pt" table-layout="fixed" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="proportional-column-width(0.2)"/><fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="proportional-column-width(1.0)"/><fo:table-body id=""><fo:table-row id=""><fo:table-cell id="" text-align="right"><fo:block end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" text-align="left">Copyright</fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell id=""><fo:block end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" text-align="left"><fo:block font-family="HelveticaNeueLTStdThin" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" margin-left="0cm" space-after="3pt" space-before="3pt" start-indent="0cm" text-indent="0cm"><opentopic-i18n:text-fragment char-set="SymbolsSuperscript">©</opentopic-i18n:text-fragment>Copyright 2015  All rights reserved</fo:block>
              </fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row id=""><fo:table-cell id="" text-align="right"><fo:block end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" text-align="left">Intended Purpose</fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell id=""><fo:block end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" text-align="left"><fo:block font-family="HelveticaNeueLTStdThin" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" margin-left="0cm" space-after="3pt" space-before="3pt" start-indent="0cm" text-indent="0cm">
                   This guide provides details of the features provided proactive recovery.</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row id=""><fo:table-cell id="" text-align="right"><fo:block end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" text-align="left">Conventions Used</fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell id=""><fo:block end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" text-align="left"><fo:block font-family="HelveticaNeueLTStdThin" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" margin-left="0cm" space-after="3pt" space-before="3pt" start-indent="0cm" text-indent="0cm">This guide uses the following format for tips and additional information:
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="20pt"/><fo:table-column column-width="100% - 32pt"/><fo:table-body><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell padding-right="5pt" start-indent="0pt"><fo:block><fo:external-graphic src="url(file:/C:/DITA-OT2.0.1_client_bin/DITA-OT2.0.1/temp/pdf/9030310-OperationsGuide/Configuration/OpenTopic/cfg/common/artwork/Notice_Tip_A3A5.svg)"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell start-indent="0pt"><fo:block border-bottom-color=" #000000" border-bottom-style=" solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-top-color=" #000000" border-top-style=" solid" border-top-width="1pt" font-family="helveticaNeueLTStdThinIt" font-size="10pt" id="" margin-bottom="3pt" margin-left="2cm" margin-top="3pt" padding="1.9pt" padding-bottom="1.9px" padding-top="1.9px" page-break-after="avoid" page-break-before="avoid" page-break-inside="avoid"><fo:inline start-indent="0cm"><fo:inline clear="both" float="left" height="20px" margin-left="0px" margin-top="0px" padding-left="0cm" page-break-after="avoid" page-break-before="avoid"/></fo:inline>  Additional information relating to the current section.</fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table>
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="20pt"/><fo:table-column column-width="100% - 32pt"/><fo:table-body><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell padding-right="5pt" start-indent="0pt"><fo:block><fo:external-graphic src="url(file:/C:/DITA-OT2.0.1_client_bin/DITA-OT2.0.1/temp/pdf/9030310-OperationsGuide/Configuration/OpenTopic/cfg/common/artwork/NOTICE_Caution_A3A5.svg)"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell start-indent="0pt"><fo:block border-bottom-color=" #000000" border-bottom-style=" solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-top-color=" #000000" border-top-style=" solid" border-top-width="1pt" font-family="helveticaNeueLTStdThinIt" font-size="10pt" id="" margin-bottom="3pt" margin-left="2cm" margin-top="3pt" padding="1.9pt" padding-bottom="1.9px" padding-top="1.9px" page-break-after="avoid" page-break-before="avoid" page-break-inside="avoid"><fo:inline start-indent="0cm"><fo:inline clear="both" float="left" height="20px" margin-left="0px" margin-top="0px" padding-bottom="0px" padding-left="1.9cm" padding-top="0px" page-break-after="avoid" page-break-before="avoid"/></fo:inline>  Indicates a hazardous situation which, if not avoided, could result in moderate injury, damage the product, or lead to loss of data.</fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table>
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="20pt"/><fo:table-column column-width="100% - 32pt"/><fo:table-body><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell padding-right="5pt" start-indent="0pt"><fo:block><fo:external-graphic src="url(file:/C:/DITA-OT2.0.1_client_bin/DITA-OT2.0.1/temp/pdf/9030310-OperationsGuide/Configuration/OpenTopic/cfg/common/artwork/NOTICE_Notice_A3A5.svg)"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell start-indent="0pt"><fo:block border-bottom-color=" #000000" border-bottom-style=" solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-top-color=" #000000" border-top-style=" solid" border-top-width="1pt" font-family="helveticaNeueLTStdThinIt" font-size="10pt" id="" margin-bottom="3pt" margin-left="2cm" margin-top="3pt" padding="1.9pt" padding-bottom="1.9px" padding-top="1.9px" page-break-after="avoid" page-break-before="avoid" page-break-inside="avoid"><fo:inline start-indent="0cm"><fo:inline/></fo:inline>  Indicates a hazardous situation which, if not avoided, may seriously impair operations.</fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table>
        </fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table>
```

And when moved as a chapter:

stage3:

```
<fo:table id="" space-after="5pt" space-after.optimum="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-before.optimum="5pt" table-layout="fixed" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="proportional-column-width(0.2)"/><fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="proportional-column-width(1.0)"/><fo:table-body id=""><fo:table-row id=""><fo:table-cell id="" text-align="right"><fo:block end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" text-align="left">Copyright</fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell id=""><fo:block end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" text-align="left"><fo:block font-family="HelveticaNeueLTStdThin" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" margin-left="0cm" space-after="3pt" space-before="3pt" start-indent="0cm" text-indent="0cm"><opentopic-i18n:text-fragment char-set="SymbolsSuperscript">©</opentopic-i18n:text-fragment>Copyright 2015 Resilient plc All rights reserved</fo:block>
              </fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row id=""><fo:table-cell id="" text-align="right"><fo:block end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" text-align="left">Intended Purpose</fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell id=""><fo:block end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" text-align="left"><fo:block font-family="HelveticaNeueLTStdThin" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" margin-left="0cm" space-after="3pt" space-before="3pt" start-indent="0cm" text-indent="0cm">
                   This guide provides details of the features provided proactive recovery.</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row id=""><fo:table-cell id="" text-align="right"><fo:block end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" text-align="left">Conventions Used</fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell id=""><fo:block end-indent="3pt" font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" margin="3pt 3pt -30mm 0mm" padding-bottom="3pt" padding-left="10mm" padding-right="30mm" padding-top="3pt" space-after="0mm" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-before="0mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="3pt" text-align="left"><fo:block font-family="HelveticaNeueLTStdThin" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" margin-left="0cm" space-after="3pt" space-before="3pt" start-indent="0cm" text-indent="0cm">This guide uses the following format for tips and additional information:
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="20pt"/><fo:table-column column-width="100% - 32pt"/><fo:table-body><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell padding-right="5pt" start-indent="0pt"><fo:block><fo:external-graphic src="url(file:/C:/DITA-OT2.0.1_client_bin/DITA-OT2.0.1/temp/pdf/9030310-OperationsGuide/Configuration/OpenTopic/cfg/common/artwork/Notice_Tip_A3A5.svg)"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell start-indent="0pt"><fo:block border-bottom-color=" #000000" border-bottom-style=" solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-top-color=" #000000" border-top-style=" solid" border-top-width="1pt" font-family="helveticaNeueLTStdThinIt" font-size="10pt" id="" margin-bottom="3pt" margin-left="2cm" margin-top="3pt" padding="1.9pt" padding-bottom="1.9px" padding-top="1.9px" page-break-after="avoid" page-break-before="avoid" page-break-inside="avoid"><fo:inline start-indent="0cm"><fo:inline clear="both" float="left" height="20px" margin-left="0px" margin-top="0px" padding-left="0cm" page-break-after="avoid" page-break-before="avoid"/></fo:inline>  Additional information relating to the current section.</fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table>
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="20pt"/><fo:table-column column-width="100% - 32pt"/><fo:table-body><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell padding-right="5pt" start-indent="0pt"><fo:block><fo:external-graphic src="url(file:/C:/DITA-OT2.0.1_client_bin/DITA-OT2.0.1/temp/pdf/9030310-OperationsGuide/Configuration/OpenTopic/cfg/common/artwork/NOTICE_Caution_A3A5.svg)"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell start-indent="0pt"><fo:block border-bottom-color=" #000000" border-bottom-style=" solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-top-color=" #000000" border-top-style=" solid" border-top-width="1pt" font-family="helveticaNeueLTStdThinIt" font-size="10pt" id="" margin-bottom="3pt" margin-left="2cm" margin-top="3pt" padding="1.9pt" padding-bottom="1.9px" padding-top="1.9px" page-break-after="avoid" page-break-before="avoid" page-break-inside="avoid"><fo:inline start-indent="0cm"><fo:inline clear="both" float="left" height="20px" margin-left="0px" margin-top="0px" padding-bottom="0px" padding-left="1.9cm" padding-top="0px" page-break-after="avoid" page-break-before="avoid"/></fo:inline>  Indicates a hazardous situation which, if not avoided, could result in moderate injury, damage the product, or lead to loss of data.</fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table>
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="20pt"/><fo:table-column column-width="100% - 32pt"/><fo:table-body><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell padding-right="5pt" start-indent="0pt"><fo:block><fo:external-graphic src="url(file:/C:/DITA-OT2.0.1_client_bin/DITA-OT2.0.1/temp/pdf/9030310-OperationsGuide/Configuration/OpenTopic/cfg/common/artwork/NOTICE_Notice_A3A5.svg)"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell start-indent="0pt"><fo:block border-bottom-color=" #000000" border-bottom-style=" solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-top-color=" #000000" border-top-style=" solid" border-top-width="1pt" font-family="helveticaNeueLTStdThinIt" font-size="10pt" id="" margin-bottom="3pt" margin-left="2cm" margin-top="3pt" padding="1.9pt" padding-bottom="1.9px" padding-top="1.9px" page-break-after="avoid" page-break-before="avoid" page-break-inside="avoid"><fo:inline start-indent="0cm"><fo:inline/></fo:inline>  Indicates a hazardous situation which, if not avoided, may seriously impair operations.</fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table>
        </fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table>
```

Comment: Use `&copy;` instead.

Comment: already did. Its not about it.

Comment: What does the XSL-FO look like? Not sure how it's making `fo:inline` a direct child of `fo:root`. I'm unable to reproduce using oXygen (which I think uses version 1.7 of DITA-OT).

Comment: I feel like I ran into this a few years ago. IIRC, I had to keyref or conkeyref the statement with the copyright symbol into place.

This guy ran into it as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809269/copyright-statement-not-building

Paging Radu! http://stackoverflow.com/users/1101698/radu-coravu

Comment: As @DanielHaley states, you should use the toolkit to export the FO being generated and examine it. It is always the first step in diagnosis.

Comment: Ok, I added generated FO. Is there any free toolkit to examine this?

Comment: I can see what could cause problem. But I am unable to paste it here (because of the limit). But I will make it short. When in preface, content of preface is placed (additionally) between two fo:page-sequence. And everything is "ok" normally (text is not shown) but when I adding copyright symbol, parser puts it within the symbol tag, and its not allowed. Now I "ONLY" need to find out why content is placed between fo:sequence.

Comment: Actually I have a question... What could cause that there is a text without a fo:block? Normally it shouldnt be allowed to place text in fo:root, am I right?

Comment: Well, I am not sure what you posted because that is not final XSL FO. There is no such thing (in XSL FO) as a opentopic-i18n:text-fragment tag. This is not the final XSL FO that is going to a formatting engine.

Comment: Hm... Then really I have no idea what is :P I am still pretty fresh in that topic, without proper training, so forgive errors like that. Anyway I managed to deal with that problem, so thank you all for help :)